# Long title crashes django site error500

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I have setup a django website on digital ocean with gunicorn and nginx. All works great, but when a user types a long title on a post, and then submits the form, the whole site crashes with an error 500. The admin site is still accessible and i can delete that post and then the site works again.

It looks like the slug cannot be created and saved with the post with a title too big because the slug itself becomes too big and this causes an error and makes any part of my page that refers to that post crash when accessed.

This is my models for title and slug

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, default='', editable=True)
```

I do still want to have a limit of 120 characters but how do i enforce it without making the site crash? Can i either make a form that stops the user from writing a long title or do i cut a title that is too long before saving the post and creating the slug?

My views part

```
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and 'form' in request.POST:
            post = form.save(commit=False)

            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.typeof = "Article"




            post.save()

            return redirect(home)
```

My forms.py is very simple no additions just listing all the fields

**Tested in the dev server and works fine, but not in the production one**
**Also, i noticed that i am only allowed about 50 characters in the title otherwise it crashes again. But only in production, not in dev**

I got an error:
value too long for type character varying(50) 
I found solutions on this and i am testing now. I will post the answer once i am done.

Comment: can you post the error traceback? and yes you can use forms to validate the [max length](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#charfield).

Comment: @NalinDobhal i cant get error log from production server and in my dev server i cant replicate the issue

Comment: why you cant get the error logs?

Comment: @NalinDobhal its running from gunicorn i cant see the errors like i do on the dev server from django itself. I will try and see if there is a way

Comment: so configure logging in your application. btw you can get gunicorn logs from /var/log/syslog

Comment: @NalinDobhal ill try that thanks

Comment: @NalinDobhal value too long for type character varying(50)

Comment: i guess that's because of [SlugField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#slugfield), the default max_length for slug field is 50, you need to change that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that slug didnt specify a max_length attribute, so the database that django created expected a smaller value. I am not an expert on this, but after adding max_value=255 on the slugfield and without changing anything else it worked. I needed to run a makemigrations and then a migrate. I restarted both gunicorn and nginx and now everything is fine.